# GlassFish 5.0 exception and port 4848 not responding

Tags: exception, glassfish, java-9

Yesterday i downloaded GlassFish 5.0 and JDK9. When I'm trying to run server with `asadmin start-domain` GlassFish send to me [exception](https://zapodaj.net/c88b3c6980b3b.png.html)

When I try to use "asadmin start-domainAfter" I got respond: "Remote server does not listen request on [localhost 4848]. Is the serwer up?"

Any can help me with this? I looked for solution at google, I tried kill process using port 4848, change port 4848 in domain.xml on another one, nothing helps.

It's my firts time with glassfish I don't know what to do. Anyone can help me?

I'm working at windows 7, InteliJ Ultimate 2017.2.4, JRE 1.8 and JDK 9.

Comment: you can edit your question and can provide additional information there. Providing additional information is comments is not good.

Comment: There is an issue tracking it here: https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/issues/22130

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GlassFish 5.0 not starting on JDK 9 is a known issue.

GlassFish 5.0 is certified only on JDK 8 (u144) as stated in the release notes:
https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/doc/5.0/release-notes.pdf

Comment: It works. I reinstalled Java and installed JDK 1.8 u44. But when I tried asadmin start-domain I had neverendig loaded nad problem with connect. At InteliJ i got port 4848 not responding. I changed port 4848 on 5357 at domain.xml but I go: Unable to connect to the localhost:5357, reason: com.intellij.javaee.process.common.WrappedException: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://localhost:5357/__asadmin/version" Any can help?

Comment: Kimoki, there appears to be some port issues. Did you check the domains/domain1/logs/server.log to see why the domain failed to start?

Comment: Yeah, and here is the latest log: https://jpst.it/15lZQ

I got java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind, I don't understand this. I tried different ports.

Comment: I checked once again. When I taskkill port 8080 I can run glassfish from CMD (asadmin start-domain), at http://localhost:8080/ I can't go to "Administration Console" I got unable connect to port 4848. When I use InteliJ I can't compile, because can't connect to 4848. When in settings i changed port 4848 -> 1841 and killed tasks from this port problem is the same.

Comment: Lol, everything is working now. My problems was created by my low knowlege. Sorry guys. After taskkill port 8080 I started domain from cmd, and later run project at InteliJ and working good. Thanks for help. Now my problems, are solved.

Answer (score 4):

I use Windows 10 and I have installed JDK and JRE for version 9 and 8u141, 8u151, 8u144 (installed for test about this problem)
For exception I had had the same problem : the command "asadmin start-version" throw an exception.

Just check the version from CMD console :

```
C:\Users\xxxxx>**java -version**
java version "9.0.1"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)
```

Problem JAVA_HOME and PATH environment viariables are JDK8u151 ???

To solve the problem, the documentation advice that :

*Alternatively, you can specifically set the Java path with the **AS_JAVA** property in the in the **as-install/config/asenv.conf** file.*

```
C:\DEVENV\glassfish5\glassfish\config>dir
 Le volume dans le lecteur C s’appelle OS
 Le numéro de série du volume est 10BF-2BBE

 Répertoire de C:\DEVENV\glassfish5\glassfish\config

08/09/2017  07:27    <DIR>          .
08/09/2017  07:27    <DIR>          ..
12/01/2018  17:44             3 516 asenv.bat
...
```

Consequently, I add the last line below :

```
set AS_IMQ_LIB=..\..\mq\lib
set AS_IMQ_BIN=..\..\mq\bin
set AS_CONFIG=..\config
set AS_INSTALL=..
set AS_DEF_DOMAINS_PATH=..\domains
set AS_DEF_NODES_PATH=..\nodes
set AS_DERBY_INSTALL=..\..\javadb
**set AS_JAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151**
```

Relaunch CMD console and start server with asadmin start-domain : it works properly....enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

> As mentioned above GlassFish 5.0 leverages new features in Java SE 8,
>   and is certified today on Java SE 8. Even though we have a lot of work
>   in front of us with the transition to the Eclipse Foundation, our
>   current intent is to certify Java SE 9 in an upcoming GlassFish 5
>   release.

JDK 9 should be supported in the next update, i.e. GlassFish 5.0.1
See end of https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/java-ee-8-is-final-and-glassfish-50-is-released

Comment: You state that _"JDK 9 should be supported in the next update, i.e. GlassFish 5.0.1"_, but the article you linked to mentions nothing about release 5.0.1; it merely states _"our current intent is to certify Java SE 9 **in an upcoming GlassFish 5 release**"_. Adding support for JDK 9 would be a significant upgrade, and the version number wouldn't just change from 5.0 to 5.0.1._

Comment: That article is now quite old. Since then quite a few things have changed! The Java EE technologies have been transfered to the Eclipse foundation as part of the Jakarta EE initiative. Eclipse GlassFish is now the venue to track all the GF evolution. See https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish/

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a mac or linux machine, add the following to `config/asenv.conf` in your glassfish installation directory.

`set AS_JAVA="path to your jdk 8"`

For example, in Mac OS it will be

```
AS_JAVA="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone having problems with NullPointerException, look out for your system PATH Variables. **Be sure that they point to an acceptable JDK** (As it was said before: GlassFish 5.0 is certified only to work on JDK **8u144**). This NullPointerException is caused by using an incompartible JDK as mentioned here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7688/gipqi/index.html

In my case the PATH variable was correctly pointing to java8u144 bin, but my PATH also contained a pointer to `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`. And someway an old version of java SDK was stored on `\ProgramData\Oracle` so GlassFish was using this old version of java as SDK.