# Which Java EE server?

Tags: java, jboss, glassfish, jetty, apache-tomee

I'm moving in to developing Web Apps using Java EE and the first problem I have is not knowing which Server to use!  There seems to be so many to chose from!

Glassfish server seems to stand out foremost (and it's top of the list) but when I try to start Glassfish 4.1.2, I get the error `GlassFish requires Java SE version 6.` and I can't download Java SE 6 for MacOSX without joining the "Oracle Club".

So which Server should I use??

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're running JDK 8, as you should.  You should not be downloading JDK 6.  It's long past the end of its support life.

Looks like the latest is version 5.  You can download it [here](https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/download).

It should be said that you don't need Java EE to write Java web apps.  Another alternative is Spring Boot.  You won't need an app server, just an executable JAR to be run on a JDK.

Comment: Thanks, downloading Glassfish 5 and trying

Comment: Now when I start the Server (Glassfish5, JDK1.8) I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at org.glassfish.admin.cli.AsadminMain.main(AsadminMain.java:57)` :/

Comment: That error looks like it's Glassfish when using JDK9... So need to change that to JDK1.8 and try again.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46398300/glassfish-5-0-exception-and-port-4848-not-responding

Answer (score 1):

Are you on OSX? You can get a JDK1.6 download here: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US

I would be very careful with JDK1.6, it's about as safe as seatbelts made from toilet paper.

Comment: I am more after which server for production.