# Nullpointer when I startup GlassFish server

Tags: glassfish

I use Glassfish application server and according to the README file, it just said open CMD, type some commands, but I got Nullpointer. I need someone to help me. I am on Windows.

```
asadmin start-domain
```

The error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.initializeServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:152)
        at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.newServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:144)
        at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.createServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:218)
        at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.createServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:224)
        at com.sun.enterprise.module.single.StaticModulesRegistry.createServiceLocator(StaticModulesRegistry.java:88)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLIContainer.getServiceLocator(CLIContainer.java:217)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLIContainer.getLocalCommand(CLIContainer.java:255)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.getCommand(CLICommand.java:231)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.executeCommand(AdminMain.java:371)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.doMain(AdminMain.java:306)
        at org.glassfish.admin.cli.AsadminMain.main(AsadminMain.java:57)
```

Comment: Finally I found it of JDK9！

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned in your comment the problem is Java 9.

Glassfish currently only works with Java 7 or Java 8.

**Related Glassfish issues on Github:**

- [asadmin start-domain fails with NullPointerException when JAVA_HOME set to JDK 9 or JDK 10 build](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/issues/22130)
- [Umbrella Issue for Glassfish testing with JDK 9](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/issues/21441)
- [[GF-JDK9] Exception when starting GF with JDK9](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/issues/21588)

The last issue contains a workaround:

```
In order to work around this issue please edit the glassfish/bin/asadmin file and change the line # to following
Old
exec "$JAVA" -jar "$AS_INSTALL_LIB/client/appserver-cli.jar" "$@"
Changed
exec "$JAVA" --add-modules java.annotations.common -jar "$AS_INSTALL_LIB/client/appserver-cli.jar" "$@"
```

**See also:**

- [GlassFish 5.0 exception and port 4848 not responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46398300/glassfish-5-0-exception-and-port-4848-not-responding)

Comment: Despite I have updated Java to version 9, getting `nullpointerexception` when I try to create a new domain on Payara AS 5.181. The OS is Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit). JDK is also 64-bit.

Comment: This results in `java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.annotations.common not found` for me

Answer (score 0):

Glassfish doesn't support Java 9 as for now.

Download Java 8 JRE and then edit the file `glassfish/bin/asadmin` and change the line

```
exec "$JAVA" -jar "$AS_INSTALL_LIB/client/appserver-cli.jar" "$@"
```

replacing `exec "$JAVA"` with the path to `java` in your Java 8 JRE, for example

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -jar "$AS_INSTALL_LIB/client/appserver-cli.jar" "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this because versions greater than java 8 is not currently supported. See [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/payara-forum/ck-ddL7f96M) . All that's needed to be done is install jdk 8 and export JAVA_HOME to point to the jdk.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your Java Version....
I had the same problem, but I change the version and it works nowadays.

But, I tried changing the Glassfish Server, the version I used, it was damaged, and with the same version but downloaded and extracted from another place it works.

Answer (score 0):

1- check your java varsion

```
java -version
```

2- if it's not java 8
install java 8:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

3-change your jdk to java8 :

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

4-rerun glassfish:

```
glassfish5/bin/asadmin start-domain
```